# WebSphere Liberty, Eclipse and wsimport

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, websphere-liberty

I have been supplied a WebServices wsdl file that I want to generate a Java Client for within Eclipse (Neon.3).  I have the latest WebSphere Liberty runtime (Full Java EE 1.7) installed and the the latest Eclipse developer tools for Eclipse.

I am finding that I get the following error:

[image]

The recipe I followed to get here was:

1. Right click my WSDL in my Eclipse project
2. Select Web Services > Generate Client
3. I am then presented with the following and click "Next"

[image]

4. I am given a final dialog shown below and then the error dialog appears.

[image]

My Liberty is installed in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wlp` and hence the mention of `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin` puzzles me (although I do have WAS ND there).

I checked in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wlp` and find that there is a `wsimport` tool contained in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/wlp/bin/jaxws`.

Reading the messages in the instruction, I installed the WAS Liberty Extended Programming Models found here `https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/addons-wlp-extended` but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible solutions based on the information provided.

1) Can you please check the Server Runtime Environments preference page (Window->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments) and ensure the Liberty runtime entry is valid and is pointing to the correct path (to the wlp folder).   If it is invalid, you need to fix this and then try again.

2) Check that your project is actually targeted to the Liberty runtime.  It appears that it is targeting the full version of WebSphere Application Server.  If that is the case, change the target to the Liberty Runtime, and then try again.